# Inno setup i18n for custom panel

Tags: internationalization, installation, inno-setup

I made a custom panel for Inno-Setup and i want internationalization for this.

Can i use the *.isl files to add my translation keys or must i use the [custommessages]? And how can i access the keys in the [code] section.

Non of the inno-setup examples using the i18n.

thx
Tom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***1. Can I modify the isl localization files ?***

It's upon you, if you modify standard *.isl files, or create your own modified ones. For sure keep in mind, that if you modify the standard ones, they might get updated by a new version of Inno Setup you install. That might be the reason why many people suggests to only create entries in the [`[CustomMessages]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=custommessagessection) section.

But you can of course create a separate language file which you'll merge with each Inno Setup update, or even better, like Miral suggests, specify your custom messages in your own *.isl file, and then in the `MessagesFile` parameter of the [`[Languages]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_languagessection.htm) section specify that file at the end of the comma separated list of files:

```
[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl,compiler:YourEnMessages.isl"
Name: "nl"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Dutch.isl,compiler:YourNlMessages.isl"
```

As the reference states for the `MessagesFile` parameter:

> When multiple files are specified, they are read in the order they are
>   specified, thus the last message file overrides any messages in
>   previous files.

So if you make only *.isl file(s) with only `[CustomMessages]` section and specify them in the script the above way, you won't break anything and you'll get the separate reusable language file(s). Structure of such custom *.isl file might look eaxctly like the `[CustomMessages]` section:

```
[CustomMessages]
SomeCustomKey=Some custom value
...
```

Making your own language files might be better for you if you're going to reuse those custom messages in many setups.

***2. How can I access custom messages from the [Code] section ?***

By using [`CustomMessage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_custommessage) function. For instance this way:

```
...

[CustomMessages]
; the following key value pair can be moved to the *.isl file into the same
; named file section, if needed; as a downside of doing that you'll need to
; keep track of changes if you update Inno Setup itself
SomeCustomKey=Some custom value

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := CustomMessage('SomeCustomKey');
  MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: I suggest never modifying the standard `.isl` files directly.  Instead, you can create a new `.isl` file that contains only those messages you wish to modify or add.  You can then use both files either by #including the standard file from your custom one, or by specifying both files (with your custom one last) in the [`MessagesFile` parameter](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_languagessection.htm).

Comment: It was really usefull, the only missing thing is how to use custom messages in code when these messages have params (e.g., %1,..., %9).

Answer (score 4):

Answer provided by @TLama is really usefull. I faced with an additional problem, which was related to use ***custom messages with params***.

To define custom messages:

Messages may take arguments, from %1 up to %9. You can rearrange the order of the arguments (i.e. move the %2 before a %1) and also duplicate arguments if needed (i.e. "%1 ... %1 %2"). On messages with arguments, use two consecutive "%" characters to embed a single "%". "%n" creates a line break.

**For example:**

```
[CustomMessages]
...
NameAndVersion=%1 version %2
...
```

And then, to use it in code section, simply use FmtMessage function together with CustomMessage function:

**Example:**

```
S := FmtMessage(CustomMessage('NameAndVersion'), ['My Program', '1.0']);
// S = 'My Program version 1.0'
```